# Removing numbers in front of Array

Tags: php

I am having arrays from my PHP

```
{"lista":[{"Grad":"Beograd"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad"},{"Grad":"Beograd"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad"},{"Grad":"Beograd"},{"Grad":"Beograd"},{"Grad":"Beograd"},{"Grad":"Kragujevac"},{"Grad":"Kragujevac"},{"Grad":"Beograd"},{"Grad":"Kragujevac"},{"Grad":"Beograd"}]}
```

and when I use:

```
$arr = array_flip(array_map('serialize', $rows));
$lista = array_map('unserialize', array_flip($arr));
echo json_encode((object) array('lista' => $lista));
```

I am getting

```
{"lista":{"19":{"Grad":"Beograd"},"18":{"Grad":"Novi_Sad"},"20":{"Grad":"Kragujevac"}}}
```

Question is how can I remove this numbers that are in front of my arrays?

Comment: Why are you using `array_flip()`?

Comment: That was a suggestion how to remove my duplicates.

Comment: loop throught the array, check if an object is a number and then remove it? edit: misread your question, you need to json_decode your string!

Comment: Can you show me how,please?

Comment: @Michael How about `array_unique();` to remove duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing

`echo json_encode((object) array('lista' => $lista));`

to

`echo json_encode((object) array('lista' => array_values($lista)));`

Note : not tested

Comment: Not tested, well, apart from testing, it also has superfluous code. So better understand how `json_encode` works or at least give others the chance by presenting a link to the manual: http://php.net/json_encode.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to populate the array as in the example in the documentation in the php manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

From PHP Site:

```
 $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

The above example will output:

```
 {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Comment: I found an answer, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

apply array_values before encoding into Json_encode

```
$lista = array_values(array_map('unserialize', array_flip($arr)));
echo json_encode((object) array('lista' => $lista));
```